# Parsing xml using c# and windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I have an xml file like this:

```
  <xml>
    <students>
      <person name=jhon/>
      <person name=jack/>
      ...
    </students>
    <teachers>
       <person name="jane" />
       <person name="jane" />
       ...
    </teachers>
  </xml>
```

If I use this code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(myxmlstring, LoadOptions.None);
foreach(XElement studentelement in xml.Descendants("person"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(studentelement.Attribute("name").Value);
}
```

Everything works fine! However, I don't know if I'm iteratng over the students or the teachers.

But when I try:

```
var a = xml.Element("students");
```

a is null!!!

How can I select a specific element in my xml document with c#?

It would be awesome if I could iterate over the students only first, fill some listboxes and the iterate over the teachers and do other stuff. :)

The xml file can`t be modified, just in case...

Finally, all I actually want with all of this is to get all the children of a specific element in my file.

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` only returns the immediate child node. To recursively browse the xml tree, use `Descendants` instead.

To successively enumerate the students then the teachers, you could do something like:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(myxmlstring, LoadOptions.None);

var students = xml.Descendants("students");
var teachers = xml.Descendants("teachers");

foreach (var studentElement in students.Descendants("person"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(studentElement.Attribute("name").Value);
}

foreach (var teacherElement in teachers.Descendants("person"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(teacherElement.Attribute("name").Value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> But when I try: var a = xml.Element("students");
>
> a is null!!!

Yes, because `xml` is the document, and there's only *one* directly element below it - called `xml`. If you use:

```
var students = xml.Root.Element("students");
```

instead, it would look for `<students>` directly beneath the root element instead, and it would work.

Or alternatively, you can use `Element` twice:

```
var students = xml.Element("xml").Element("students");
```

Or use `Descendants`, of course.

Additionally, you can get to an element's parent element with the `Parent` property... so if you wanted to iterate over *all* `person` elements and use the parent element name for some reason, you could certainly do that.