# Get string form XML file by attribute

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, nsxmlparser

I have a XML file

```
<resources>
  <string name="aaa">Hotel</string>
  <string name="bbb">Home</string>
  <string name="ccc">Castle</string>
  ...
<resourses>
```

I tried got content string (Hotel or Home ...) in  using special name of this (aaa, bbb ..).

Comment: What have you already tried? What where your problems/errors?

Comment: And what has nsxmlparser got to do with this?

Comment: Will give you everything: (See the 1st answer)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588868/parsing-xml-using-c-sharp-and-windows-phone-7

Comment: sorry. I'm a starter programing. I work follow that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750678/getting-attribute-value-of-an-xml-document-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstring, LoadOptions.None);
var resources= xml.Descendants("resources");
foreach (var resourceElement in resources.Descendants("Hotel"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(resourceElement.Attribute("name").Value);
}
```